# Has anyone ever lost a lawsuit for giving a bad employment reference? Has a case like this even happened in the U.S.?

Tags: united-states, employment

It's is a well-known "fact" that companies can be sued for giving a bad employment reference about a former employee and that, because of this, many HR departments refuse to give *any* type of reference other than simply confirming employment dates.

However, has there actually ever even been a case where the former employee sued, much less won, simply for giving a bad, but truthful, reference?

Comment: Maybe ask at https://law.stackexchange.com where some may know of cases that have been brought.  example https://law.stackexchange.com/q/53400/12730

Comment: Not in the US, and not a court case, but would a UK employment tribunal decision against the former-employee count?  https://www.gov.uk/employment-tribunal-decisions/mrs-n-leeks-v-norfolk-and-norwich-university-hospitals-nhs-foundation-trust-3303975-2018

Comment: Please read [Defamation Vs. Negligent Referral](https://gbr.pepperdine.edu/2010/08/defamation-vs-negligent-referral/) *A policy of giving only basic employee references may lead to liability.* There is quite a lot written about the topic to be found, such as supreme court decisions, but the question belongs on Law not Skeptics.